# How long will Firebase Analytics Data be exported to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have enabled the BigQuery integration in Firebase Console and I have some issues about this :

1. How long will Firebase Analytics Data be exported to BigQuery ? I had the integration from Firebase to BigQuery, somehow Firebase Analytics Data export was disabled by somebody. I just enabled it yesterday around 17:00, and there is no data updated in BigQuery so far.
2. Why Firebase Analytics Data will be updated even thought the data is moved from intraday data set to event data set ? I find the data will be updated in around 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the latency, your first question, you should pay attention to two topics:

1. **Client to Server latency**

Firebase does not stream down data from the client's device constantly. Instead, the analytics data is batched up and sent down to the Firebase server when the local data is one hour old. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html).

2. **Firebase to BigQuery**

After linking your Firebase project with BigQuery, the data will be streamed to BigQuery as soon as Firebase Analytics receives it, [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html).

The data flow and latency would be as follows (image taken from the [documentation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html)):

[image]

About your second question, everyday your data will be streamed in nearly real time to the `appevents_intraday_` temporary table in BigQuery. This table collects all the data from the current day and it allows you to query against this data. At the end of the day, this data will be moved to its `appevents_` permanent table and the temporary intra day table will be cleaned up.

I must point that, the only difference is that the intra day table do not have *lifetime value data* and *campaign information* (the ***traffic_source*** record), which is present in the `appevents_` table.

I would also encourage you to have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGVbOrUhP58) provided by Firebase. It explains all the dynamics between Firebase and BigQuery.

Comment: after enabling bigquery on analytics, it will send data since when? I did it and mine is showing up only last 3 days