# How to see the Firebase Analytics data on BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

The scenario here is that I have my Firebase( just Analytics-Data) project linked to BigQuery. but when i check on the bigQuery to see the dataset it's not appear there and i don't know which name/id has.

I highly appreciate your support. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765), when you link your Firebase Project to BigQuery,a corresponding dataset will be created. This dataset  can be found, in BigQuery, ***under your project id*** and it will be named as your app. In case, that you have both IOS and Android versions of your app, two datasets will be created as follows:

[image]

The above image was taken from the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/using-bigquery-and-firebase-analytics-to-understand-your-mobile-app).

Furthermore, in addition to your ***app_events*** table, under your app's name, you will have ***apps_events_intraday***, which will receive data near real time from Firebase. In other words, as soon as Firebase receives the data from the app it will transfer it to the *intraday* table in BigQuery. Whereas, the ***app_events*** table will be uploaded once per day, [link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html).

Lastly, keep in mind that the data generated by your app can take up to 1 hour to be sent to Firebase which then will be nearly instantly sent to BigQuery. You can read more about the latency [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673581/how-long-will-firebase-analytics-data-be-exported-to-bigquery/61679419#61679419).